# SQL Server odd Performance results when querying/not querying checking for NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, database-performance

I have to modify a query that is checking that a given date falls between the StartDate and EndDate fields of some View result set.
Since there is no row with null values in those fields, the following queries offer exactly the same results.

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeView
WHERE (StartDate <= GETDATE())
    AND (EndDate >= GETDATE())
    

SELECT *
FROM SomeView
WHERE ((StartDate IS NULL) OR (StartDate <= GETDATE()))
    AND ((EndDate IS NULL) OR (EndDate >= GETDATE()))
```

I know this is not always going to necessarily be the case, it will depend on the data, but that´s not my question now.

If I run those queries, the second one is always 3-5 times faster than the first one, even though it seems it´s doing some unneeded extra work.
To be honest, I have tried to see the execution plan, but since this View comes from a HUGE query with several JOINs from other tables and views, I cannot put my finger on what it is SQL Server really doing to check for these dates.
How is this possible? Shouldn´t it be the other way around?

Comment: You have a view that joins to other views - the further down the rabbit hole you go the less likely SQL Server is going to build an optimal plan. Attach both actual execution plans using [Paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan)

Comment: I am afraid that I cannot paste the full execution plan here, for confidentiality reasons (the real query belongs to a customer database). Sorry. But nonetheless, no matter how the View is built, shouldn´t the first query be doing less work than the second one? The second one is ORing with a condition that is never met.

Comment: I don´t think is relevant to the question, but I have edited it anyway. And you are right.

Comment: @Ada Stop assuming. If you are truly trying to understand the issue then you need to examine the actual execution plans to understand why there is a difference. If you won't post them (or the DDL) then no one else can help you. But you have a "good" query so I suggest you add a comment to it to reflect this situation and move on.

Comment: please show the query plan for both queries, so that we can see itf there is any change and which

Comment: @Ada if you won't provide the execution plans you'll need to reproduce the issue with a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), without either I can't see how anyone can provide a concrete explanation.

Comment: If you are running the queries back to back, it may just be the case that the second is finding most or all of the needed data already cached in memory. If you swap them, do the results change? Sometimes when I'm running performance tests, it may be useful to clean out any previously cached  data using the command [DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-dropcleanbuffers-transact-sql). Best used with a dedicated test database, as it may adversely affect performance for other database users.

Comment: SentryOne Plan Explorer can obfuscate query plans. Then please share them via https://pastetheplan.com. This question is not answerable without this information

Comment: Most likely there is some statistics assumption coming from that `OR` that causes the compiler to give a completely different plan

Answer (score 0):

if  StartDate can be null also then

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeView
WHERE ((StartDate IS NULL) )
    AND ((EndDate IS NULL) )
union all
SELECT *
FROM SomeView
WHERE ((StartDate IS NOT NULL) and (StartDate <= '31/03/2022 0:00:00'))
    AND ((EndDate IS NOT NULL) and  (EndDate >= '31/03/2022 0:00:00'))
```

Guess this is just ur example,though
`StartDate` and `EndDate` should be `Datetime` data type

EndDate should be `'01/04/2022 0:00:00'`

Edited : Guess `StartDate` and `EndDate` is  `nullable`  in your database.So optmizer also search for Not Null row to filter out.
If `StartDate` and `EndDate` was  `Not null` then your first query was faster.

If you second query is faster then I will still use this query

```
SELECT *
    FROM SomeView
    WHERE ((StartDate IS NOT NULL) and (StartDate <= '31/03/2022 0:00:00'))
        AND ((EndDate IS NOT NULL) and  (EndDate >= '31/03/2022 0:00:00'))
```

Comment: I am not looking for a third way to achieve those results. The two queries offer the same results because the is no one row in the View with either StartDate or EndDate null. My question is why the second one much faster if the only thing is doing is checking an extra condition that is never met. The first one seems to be doing much less work (as always, having in mind that both offer exactly the same results).

Comment: @Ada, read my edited.

Comment: I have tried this third option @Kumar (because this is the one that is actually equivalent to my first query no matter the data). And it takes approximately the same amount of time, too, what makes sense. The second query considerably outperforms both. And I don´t know why.